# I'm stuck on trying to sort by the given date

Tags: python

I seem to not be able to sort it by the date in the def display_assignment_by_due_date(self) part of the code. I tried the .sort() but it didn't work. Am I doing it wrong or is there a different way?

```
class Assignment:
    def __init__(self):
        self.assignments = []

    def add(self, due_date, course):
        add_course = [due_date, course]
        if add_course not in self.assignments:
            self.assignments.append(add_course)
        else:
            return Nothing
    
    def remove(self, due_date, course):
        remove_course = [due_date, course]
        if remove_course in self.assignments: 
            self.assignments.remove(remove_course)
        else: 
            return Nothing

    def display_assignment(self):
        print("Display assignments by order they are entered.")
        for assignment in self.assignments:
            print('Due Date: ' + assignment[0] + ', Assignment: ' + assignment[1])

    def display_assignment_by_due_date(self):
        print("Display assignments by due dates.")
        #-->This is the part I'm having trouble with. 
        for assignment in self.assignments:
            print('Due Date: ' + assignment[0] + ', Assignment: ' + assignment[1])
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    assignment = Assignment()
    assignment.add("10/21/2020", "COMP120")
    assignment.add("10/30/2020", "MATH220")
    assignment.add("10/07/2020", "ITEC136")
    assignment.add("10/14/2020", "ENGL120")

    assignment.display_assignment()
    assignment.display_assignment_by_due_date()

    assignment.remove("10/14/2020", "ENGL120")

    assignment.display_assignment()
    assignment.display_assignment_by_due_date()
```

Comment: A simple `self.assignments.sort()` should work, but only because your dates are all in the same month.  If you entered the dates as "yyyy/mm/dd", then sort would always be OK.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I see what I did wrong. I was putting the .sort() into the print().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`from datetime import datetime`

and:

```py
def display_assignment_by_due_date(self):
        print("Display assignments by due dates.")
        ## Here        
        self.assignments.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date[0], "%m/%d/%Y"))
        for assignment in self.assignments:
            print('Due Date: ' + assignment[0] + ', Assignment: ' + assignment[1])
```

I'm using .sort with datetime.strptime